# TRUFFLE MIGRATE: Saving migration to chain.Error: Error: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, error, migration

> $ truffle migrate

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 0x1ff973cafa8000


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xb1c862e8e0ef63c49e711d9816606ece17f3b542a63f3ee7231134c0893ecc5c
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x1504492B6573ef3A9a14dAe6Cc09563Fb4781565
   > block number:        7
   > block timestamp:     1560679987
   > account:             0x8110D6959350570944fa2484E63D5803730e4406
   > balance:             99999.57577006
   > gas used:            261393
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00522786 ETH


   ⠙ Saving migration to chain.Error: Error: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Object.run (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:92:1)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Node v8.9.4
```

Can't find the issue to the problem.. Just trying to migrate the very basic Migration contract and it throws this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved with

> $ npm i -g truffle@v5.0.5